# Norm equality in the dual space

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Suppose $X$ is normed complex space and $h:X\to \mathbb{R}$ is bounded linear functional (real). Prove that $f:X\to \mathbb{C}$ defined by $f(x)=h(x)-ih(ix)$ belongs to the dual space of $X$ and $\left \| f \right \|=\left \| h \right \|$.

I proved that $f$ belongs to the dual space of $X$, however I couldn't show the equality $\left \| f \right \|=\left \| h \right \|$.

I'd appreciate a hint on how to show this. Thanks.

Comment: Please include your work showing that $f$ is in the dual. Did you already get $||f|| \leq ||h||?$

Comment: I can show only the opposite direction. Any hint?

Comment: How did you show $f$ is in the dual?

Answer (score 3):

Showing that $\|f\|\leq\|h\|$ is the only part you seem to be stuck on.

For $x\in X$, write $f(x)=re^{i\theta}$. Then $|f(x)|=f(e^{-i\theta}x)=r=h(e^{-i\theta}x)=|h(e^{-i\theta}x)|\leq\|h\|\|e^{-i\theta}x\|=\|h\|\|x\|$.

(I probably read this trick in Douglas's *Banach algebra techniques in operator theory*.)